# C# check file path including zipped folder

Tags: c#, zip

I am trying to verify a file path that includes a zipped folder but for some reason, when given a path that exists (which I have checked), my `File.Exists()` method is only ever returning `false`.

Filepath example: `C:\Users\richa_000\Desktop\exporter\forex\fxcm\minute\audjpy\my_zipped_folder\is_thisFile_here.csv`

Does `File.Exists()` work with zipped folders? Is this what is throwing off my check?

`Program.cs`

```
namespace TradingDaysFileChecker
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var startDate = new DateTime(2007, 04, 01);
            var endDate = new DateTime(2016, 07, 25);
            var dataFilePath = @"C:\Users\richa_000\Desktop\exporter\forex\fxcm\minute\";

            var securityType = SecurityType.Forex;
            var ticker = TickType.Trade;
            var marketHoursDatabase = MarketHoursDatabase.FromDataFolder();
            var market = Market.FXCM;
            var symbol = Symbol.Create(ticker.ToString(), securityType, market);
            var marketHoursDbEntry = marketHoursDatabase.GetEntry(symbol.ID.Market, symbol.Value, symbol.ID.SecurityType);

            var exchange = new ForexExchange(marketHoursDbEntry.ExchangeHours);
            var validTradingDays = new DateHandler(startDate, endDate, dataFilePath).IterateOverDateRange(exchange);

            var forexSecuritiesFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(dataFilePath);

            foreach (var validDay in validTradingDays)
            {
                foreach (var forexSecurity in forexSecuritiesFolders)
                {
                    var securityName = new DirectoryInfo(forexSecurity).Name;
                    var formattedFolderName = validDay.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "_quote"; // Checks folder name 
                    var formattedFileName = validDay.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + securityName + "_minute_quote";

                    var dataFile = dataFilePath + securityName + @"\" + formattedFolderName + @"\" + formattedFileName;

                    if (!File.Exists(dataFile))
                    {
                        // Some logic round here
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not actually such thing as a zipped folder. There's a zip archive that's stored as a file. That archive contains its own file structure which resembles folders and files, but that has nothing to do with the operating system's folder/file structure. Windows Explorer does a good job of faking it, but you'll notice limitations in Explorer when browsing in a .zip file.

You'll have to analyze the zip archive if you want to determine whether or not it contains a file. To do that, you'll want to check out the [ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx) class.